# Can Windows CE buttons sport an image?

Tags: c#, button, compact-framework, windows-ce

Due to real estate/space constraints, I want to put a Printer icon on a button rather than the text "Print"

Yet I see no obvious way to do that (No "Image" property or so on the button).

Is it possible (without jumping sideways through flaming hoops)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard button does not support images, no.  You have to create a custom control.  This was such a common request that [Microsoft released an article on MSDN showing how to do it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx).

I'd argue that they would have been better served just creating the support in the Button (after all, they had several releases after that article) but they didn't ask me.